# Why did Livewire and Supergirl appear in The New Batman Adventures?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe

I’m currently watching *The New Batman Adventures* animated series and the thing that I don't understand is why Livewire (aka Electro Girl) suddenly appeared in the series. She is supposed to be from Superman universe. Then out of the blue Supergirl came too.

I understand that at that time both Batman and Superman were two mainstream superheroes and new episodes were released of both shows. But still, why were they interconnected?

I understand that this is the same DC Universe and that it is physically possible (since Gotham and Metropolis are adjacent cities near NY) for them to meet, but it kind of irritates me.

I kind of believe it was done for the comparison of the characters. But what to compare? Super powers vs no super powers? Weird.

P.S. I sincerely believe that *The New Batman Adventures* are tacky (not sure about *Batman Beyond*)

Comment: “I understand that this is the same DC Universe and that it is physically possible (since Gotham and Metropolis are adjacent cities near NY) for them to meet, but it kind of irritates me.” Why?

Comment: “I understand that at that time both Batman and Superman were two mainstream superheroes” — *were*? Are they not considered mainstream superheroes any more? Have they slipped away into obscurity?

Comment: Have you never seen a TV show or comic book with guest appearances before?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention in your question, Batman and Superman share a fictional universe. It's very common for such crossovers to occur within a single continuity and narrative universe, and in fact, many see it as one of the primary advantage of a wide-spread, shared universe such as the ones managed by DC Comics.

Superman and Batman, specifically, go way back. In some continuities, they founded the Justice League of America together. This list of Superman appearances in the [Batman Wiki](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman) show Superman appearing alongside Batman, at the very least, in the animated shows Superfriends, Batman Beyond, Justice League, Justice League Unlimited, Batman: The Brave And The Bold, The Dark Knight Returns, and many more. So there should be no surprise, and certainly no *problem* with these two heroes (and their various enemies, sidekicks or nieces) showing up in each other's shows.

Regarding your last question about powers, it is quite well established that despite not having any super powers, Batman is one of the only DC heroes with the capacity to stop Superman if necessary. He keeps a stock of kryptonite ready for just that eventuality.

Comment: I guess i wont like series as much now because the setting is not as gothic as it had been as I used to watch The Batman Animated Series. It is more friendly and comic in the newer ersions

Comment: Batman is usually seen as a grim and brooding superhero, but that's mostly been the case from the 80's and onwards. The old 60's TV show had him campy and silly. In the older comics, he would sometimes be accompanied by an annoying alien/imp, Bat-Mite. In the newer Brave and the Bold series, he's also back to being a daring crimefighter, not a brooding anti-hero. Batman is a lot of things. :)